# Properly compare DatetimeOffset without Time in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I've been testing a few approaches to compare two `DateTimeOffset` objects in LINQ to Entities, but I'm not really sure which one is the most efficient and the actual proper way of doing it.

I tried the following:

```
SomeTable.Where(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.StartUtc) <= intendedDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.EndUtc) >= intendedDate);
```

which generated this big complex query for the comparison:

```
((convert (datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[StartUtc], 102) + ' 00:00:00 ' +  Right(convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[StartUtc], 121), 6)  ,  102)) <= @p__linq__1) AND ((convert (datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[EndUtc], 102) + ' 00:00:00 ' +  Right(convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[EndUtc], 121), 6)  ,  102)) >= @p__linq__2)
```

Also tried `DiffDays`, which generated a more readable query

```
((DATEDIFF (day, [Extent1].[StartUtc], '2016-11-01 00:00:00 -02:00')) >= 0) AND ((DATEDIFF (day, '2016-11-01 00:00:00 -02:00', [Extent1].[EndUtc])) >= 0)
```

but this query takes time into account, I can't have that.

I'm no expert, but the first query seems really long and complex for such a simple requirement. Is this the case when I should use raw SQL instead of LINQ with EF? I can't decide which is the most efficient approach.
I feel like `CAST('2016-11-02 00:00:00 AM -02:00' AS DATE)` is much simpler and thus more performant than the query EF generates.

What's the best course of action here?

Comment: Use the 'Date' Property which will truncate time to Midnight then get the difference between dates.  A DateTime is stored in computer as a double with the integer portion being the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the fraction being the current time/24 (ie 3.5 hours/24 hours).

Comment: @jdweng `Date` property is not supported by L2E

Answer (score 0):

How about being tricky with the contained times?

```
var cmpStartDate = intendedDate.AddDays(1);

var ans = SomeTable.Where(a => a.StartUtc < cmpStartDate && a.EndUtc > intendedDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)));
```